# Debug Phonegap/Cordova appllication in weinre

Tags: android, cordova, weinre

I have a problem with debug my phonegap application. I want to connect to weinre server from my android emulator. I try to do it on my project and I can't connect. So i try to create completely new cordova project and i still can not connect and debug. This is what I'm doing:

Create new projct

```
cordova create test com.phonegap.test
cordova platform add android
```

Then i edit index.html file and add this line

```
<script src="http://10.0.2.2:9090/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

As I found 10.0.2.2 IP address is the adres i can connect from android emulator to host.

Next in config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And for sure

```
  <feature name="debug-server" required="true">
    <param name="domain" value="http://10.0.2.2:9090"/>
    <param name="key" value="SOME_KEY"/>
  </feature>
```

and in in android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

then i ran the weinre server with command:

```
weinre --httpPort 9090 --boundHost -all-
```

finally I compile my project like this:

```
cordova build
cordova install
```

So I install my app in android emulator with  4.0.1 android.

But...... nothing is happend. I don't see an connection on my weinre client side.

Every thing with adressses is ok. When i type 10.0.2.2:9090 in emulator browswer, i can see weired page.

But i can't run in compiled app. If it's matter i user Ubuntu 14.